# Few previous values of list(duplicates) are not cleared on state change

Tags: html, reactjs

I am displaying this prodsList data in a table. I replace prodsList with newProdsList which is completely different.

If there are duplicates in prodsList previously one of each duplicate get stuck on page and don't go away even if I replace the prodsList completely with newProdsList.

When this happens if I set prodsList to [] than I can see the error that prodsList is empty but still each of those duplicate don't go away.

How can I handle this situation I have to deal with this type of data where ids can repeat.

```
setFormData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        prodsList: newProdsList,
      }));
```

Data in prodsList which is rendered on page.

```
[
    {
        "id": "901166",
        "label": "901166",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "901166",
        "Part_PartDescription": "HARMONY SS SINGLE LH/BOWL INSET SINK 780 1TH",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "160.90000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "424230",
        "label": "424230",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424230",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) SINK MIXER CHROME #50000",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "414508",
        "label": "414508",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "414508",
        "Part_PartDescription": "VINCENT VANITY BASIN 550MM 1TH WH #G201W1TH",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "101.45000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "424212",
        "label": "424212",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424212",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) FIXED BASIN MIXER CHROME #50013",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "901172",
        "label": "901172",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "901172",
        "Part_PartDescription": "HARMONY SS 1.75 LH BOWL INSET SINK 1080 1TH",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "210.25000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "424230",
        "label": "424230",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424230",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) SINK MIXER CHROME #50000",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "414508",
        "label": "414508",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "414508",
        "Part_PartDescription": "VINCENT VANITY BASIN 550MM 1TH WH #G201W1TH",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "101.45000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "424212",
        "label": "424212",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424212",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) FIXED BASIN MIXER CHROME #50013",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "415620",
        "label": "415620",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "415620",
        "Part_PartDescription": "HARMONY BASSINI WF SUITE BCK/ENT STD SC SEAT",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "568.90000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "415620",
        "label": "415620",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "415620",
        "Part_PartDescription": "HARMONY BASSINI WF SUITE BCK/ENT STD SC SEAT",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "568.90000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    }
]
```

new Data which replaces the prodsList.

```
[
    {
        "id": "014005",
        "label": "014005",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "1.400",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "15.400",
        "Part_PartNum": "014005",
        "Part_PartDescription": "LEN ZINC PLATED THREADED ROD 1000XM11",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "14.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    }
]
```

Values that after I replace don't go away from page.(new value is also displayed)

```
[
 {
        "id": "424230",
        "label": "424230",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424230",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) SINK MIXER CHROME #50000",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "414508",
        "label": "414508",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "414508",
        "Part_PartDescription": "VINCENT VANITY BASIN 550MM 1TH WH #G201W1TH",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "101.45000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "424212",
        "label": "424212",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "424212",
        "Part_PartDescription": "MENO (GANA) FIXED BASIN MIXER CHROME #50013",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "93.00000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "415620",
        "label": "415620",
        "discount": "0.000",
        "calculatedTax": "0.000",
        "quantity": "1",
        "discountPercentage": "0.00",
        "subTotal": "0.000",
        "Part_PartNum": "415620",
        "Part_PartDescription": "HARMONY BASSINI WF SUITE BCK/ENT STD SC SEAT",
        "Part_UnitPrice": "568.90000",
        "PartBin_BinNum": ""
    },
]
```

Comment: Need more info considering the error and the code.

Comment: @YouhanaSheriff I have added the complete information the problem is with duplicate values. I can't do anything about that is the nature of data I am dealing with.

Comment: @Arslankhan Can you provide further details on how you are creating the newProdsList , that will help to debug the issue further.